# Как в зависимости от фотографии подобрать тип у background-size?

Tags: html, css

Есть большие фото которые могут растянуться в background image и со свойством cover нормально выглядит, а вот со свойством contain нет, потому что обрезаются углы, это лучше подходит для фото товаров каких нибудь. Так вот, как можно определить какое свойство лучше подобрать к background image в зависимости от фото. Чтобы в любом случае хорошо выглядело? Когда то cover когда contain

Comment: Самый простой способ:
Подготовить картинки с одинаковым соотношением сторон.

Comment: Просто картинки загружают пользователи, бывают разные, по стандарту я установил cover, но бывают фото которые лучше не растягивать...

Comment: Самый простой способ: Добавить пользователю самостоятельный выбор того, будет отображаться его картинка как `cover` или как `contain`. Либо как делают многие - сделать единую форму и пусть пользователь будет сам ответственен за то, как будет отображаться добавленная им картинка.